# Yocto: meta-debian errors for cl-som-imx7

Tags: debian, yocto, openembedded, imx7

I can build a yocto image for cl-som-imx7, but when i add the meta-debian layer, I get a huge python trace with a few errors. I followed the following cl-som-imx7 guide for yocto and the base image works fine. 
[Here is the error](https://pastebin.com/nLjjP4B7)

This is my bblayer.conf file:

```
POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION = "2"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BSPDIR := "${@os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(d.getVar('FILE', True)) + '/../..')}"

BBFILES ?= ""
BBLAYERS = " \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/poky/meta \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/poky/meta-poky \
  \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia \
  \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-fsl-arm \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-fsl-arm-extra \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-fsl-demos \
"
##Freescale Yocto Project Release layer
BBLAYERS += " ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-fsl-bsp-release/imx/meta-bsp "
BBLAYERS += " ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-fsl-bsp-release/imx/meta-sdk "
BBLAYERS += " ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-browser "
BBLAYERS += " ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-gnome "
BBLAYERS += " ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-networking "
BBLAYERS += " ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-python "
BBLAYERS += " ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-filesystems "
BBLAYERS += " ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-qt5 "
BBLAYERS += " \
    ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-compulab \
    ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-xfce \
    ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-dspworks \
    ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-debian \
"
BBLAYERS += " ${BSPDIR}/sources/../sources/meta-uim "
```

Comment: What's branch do you use? meta-debian doesn't support rocko or sumo. I think its still in morty.

Comment: I am using the imx-4.1-krogoth

Comment: Merging meta-debian with poky or openembedded is tricky as both the layers provide the same software.

Comment: Yocto itself is tricky. Any workaround to generate a custom debian rootfs for cl-imx7?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you take this up with the meta-debian maintainers directly: meta-debian basically doesn't place nicely with any other layers apart from the exact configuration the maintainers use.